# Shadow for UIView like the shadow of a building

Tags: ios, uiview, shadow

I need to add a shadow to a `UIView`. Imagine it like a building seen from the above.

Please look at this image,

[image]

My code:

```
//creating the view
UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100)];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[view layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[[view layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];

//adding the view to viewcontroller
[self.view addSubview:view];

//adding shadow to the view
view.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
view.layer.cornerRadius = 50; // if you like rounded corners
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
view.layer.shadowRadius = 10;
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
```

This code does not get the result I am looking for.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think it's directly possible to do it like that. You'll have to find a hacky way, like creating a "shadow view".

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting a shadow path. For example:

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(size.width * 0.33f, size.height * 0.66f)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(size.width * 0.66f, size.height * 0.66f)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(size.width * 1.15f, size.height * 1.15f)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(size.width * -0.15f, size.height * 1.15f)];
imgView.layer.shadowPath = path.CGPath;
```

A detailed tutorial can be found here: http://nachbaur.com/blog/fun-shadow-effects-using-custom-calayer-shadowpaths